# why it is printing Integer

Tags: java

why it is printing Integer?
At the time of compilation, the method call bound to class A's method.
I hope in B I am not overriding. creating a other method means method overloading with different classes.
but what is happening at run time?

```
class A{

void method(Integer i)
{
    System.out.println("Integer");

}
}
class B extends A
{

void method(int i)
{
    System.out.println("Int");
}  
}
public class Puzzle{
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        A a = new B();
        a.method(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: `method(int i)` is not an override of `method(Integer i)`. It's an overload. It's normal that the A `method` has been invoked.

Comment: method doesn't have same signature so it not override it is overloaded so that it is directly taking int not Integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B` has two different methods called `method`: one declared by `A`, which is `method(Integer)`, and one declared by `B`, which is `method(int)`.

Since your variable `a` is of type `A`, a call to `a.method()` must refer to a method provided by class `A`, which is `method(Integer)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your methods don't share the same signature.
`void method(int i)` **is not equal** to `void method(Integer i)` - the first one uses primitive type. Second one uses Object Integer.

If you change method in A to method(int i) you can then `override the method` of `A`, so `in your subclass`:

```
@Override
void method(int i)
{
    System.out.println("Int");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

B doesn't override the method called "method" because it is not the same type of parameter of your method in A (Integer).

int is a primitive type while Integer is a class.

B method should be :

```
@Override
void method(Integer i)
{
    System.out.println("Int");
}
```

The annotation `@Override` is here to tell the class should override a method. It is a good practice but not necessary (I would work without it). If you put it with your current code you would have an error because method doesn't override any method.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: If that is what he wants ;-)

Comment: Incorrect as you are missing one very important thing if you are going to do it this way, I have given -1 but I am willing to remove if this is added.

Comment: I add override annotation but I don't think it's that. I am pretty curious now. What did you mean ? What have I forgetten ?

Comment: It was the override annotation. You were overriding the method from class A in class B with the same parameters so it was an override and not an overload or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `@Override` annotation is for - add `@Override` when you think you're overriding and the compiler will tell you if you're wrong in thinking so.

If you add `@Override` to the `B`'s `method(int i)`, the compiler will give you an error telling you that you're not in fact overriding it, because the signatures differ - namely the method has different parameter type that's not a superclass of parent's parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

The signatures of the method of A and that of B are not the same. The method in A takes an object integer (Integer) as parameter while that of B takes a primitive integer (int) as parameter. So you are not really overriding the method of A in B. To do so, change the signature of the method B to be like that of A.

```
class A{

   void method(Integer i){
      System.out.println("Integer");
   }

}

class B extends A{

   @Override
   void method(Integer i){
       System.out.println("Int");
   }  

}

public class Puzzle{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      A a = new B();
      a.method(20);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reference is of type `A` - it does not recognize methods declared in type `B` in compile time, even though the may exist in runtime. The `int` literal `20` is then autoboxed to a `java.lang.Integer`, and `method(Integer)` is called.

If you were to declare the reference as `B`, the `method(int)` would be a better fit to your argument, and would be have been called.